# Unicode Char Counter - a userscript for making SE's character counter aware of non-ASCII chars ‍♂️

Tags: script, questions, editing

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

Live preview of the new counter:

[image: counting characters in a sample post title]

The counter also preserves the "heatmap" colour coding:

[image: new counter preserving color changes]

### About

> Disclaimer: please note that the script **will not** allow you to submit more characters than you can now.
>
> SE still validates as if the multi-unit char like ‍♂️ was 5 chars, but at least now you are not being fed misinformation.
>
> I will investigate if this is possible to bypass the restriction legally in later versions of the script.

Unicode Char Counter is a natural extension of my response to this post on Meta Stack Overflow:

[Count Unicode characters as single characters in question titles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/410786/11407695)

What if the character counter could indeed account for Unicode characters from [supplemental planes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode))?

No need to wait 6 to 8 weeks for this to happen: with UCC you can observe the correct information right now and compare it live to how many characters Stack Exchange's validation thinks you are entering.

#### License

The script is licensed under the [GPL-3.0-or-later](https://spdx.org/licenses/GPL-3.0-or-later) license.

#### Download

[Install](https://github.com/userscripters/unicode-char-counter/raw/master/dist/modern/index.user.js) | [Minified](https://github.com/userscripters/unicode-char-counter/raw/master/dist/modern/index.min.user.js)

The script *doesn't need* a userscript manager to work (but includes necessary headers).

#### Platform

Version number means "works in and above":

| Chrome | Opera | Firefox | Edge | IE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ✔ 92.0.4515.131 | ✔ 78.0.4093.112 | ✔ 91.0 | ✔ 92.0.902.73 | no |

Userscript managers:

| Greasemonkey | Tampermonkey | Violentmonkey |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ✔ 4.11 | ✔ 31 | ? |

### Contact

Author: [Oleg Valter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11407695/oleg-valter)

Organization: [UserScripters](https://github.com/userscripters)

Please, submit bug reports [on the source repository](https://github.com/userscripters/unicode-char-counter/issues).

Before adding a new one, please check if it hasn't been raised before.

You can also [drop by to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214345/userscript-newbies-and-friends), we are a friendly bunch.

### Code

[Source code](https://github.com/userscripters/unicode-char-counter) written in TypeScript.

Contributions are welcome, you can always [submit a PR here](https://github.com/userscripters/unicode-char-counter/pulls).